# SUBTOTAL formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]I need a formula that uses the SUBTOTAL formula in a FILTERED table (Range A2:B50).
Column A contains Name and column B the amount in sheet1.
A1 contains the criteria name and in B1, I am looking for a formula that sums the amounts if it finds the criteria name (table Range A2:B50)
Does anyone know how I can solve this with a formula?

Comment: Check the function `SUMIF`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply , but the SUMIF does not exclude filtered values in the table:(

Comment: OOpps. missed the "FILTERED". And I guess the filter is arbitrarily set, right? In that case, I'm afraid it is beyond my knowledge. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, the table has a preset filter that excludes some unwanted values. Therefore I can’t use the SUMIF. So I need to use the Subtotal, but only to sum the values in column B equal to the name in A1 :)

Comment: you might be able to use SUMIFS and include the criteria of your preset filters so those values would still be excluded.  You MIGHT also get better responses if you supply 3-4 lines of sample data (data is preferred over a screen shot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the answer given in this link:
https://superuser.com/questions/709709/combining-sumif-and-subtotal-for-dynamic-subtotal

This formula should work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET($B$2,ROW($B$2:$B$50)-ROW($B$2),,1)),--($A$2:$A$50=$A$1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day!!